# Delete a record successful, but it delete all records in the database in windows forms 2

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

Here is the of datagridview (photo) when i run the program:

[image]

Here is the photo of my GUI in program:

[image]

I want when the user select "ID 9" and click the "delete" button, it will delete the selected row also delete it at database.

How could i do that? I mean, what should i put in my command? I know my command is missing the "WHERE" clause, but i don't know what to put in the "WHERE" clause.

Here is the code that i have been doing right now (the following code is delete all row in a single click)

```
deleteButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DeleteRecord);

private DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        string query = "DELETE FROM [Record]";
                        conn.Open();

                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                            {
                                DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                                adapter.Update(ds);
                                dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
}
```

Now, my problem is, how do i delete it from datagridview and update it to the database when the user select a single row? Please help. Thanks.

**EDIT** i already tried this code:

```
    deleteButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DeleteRecord);

 private void DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            string strID = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            if (fifthForm.comboBox1.Text == "English")
            {
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string query = "DELETE FROM [Record] WHERE [ID] = @ID";
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                        {
                            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                            cmd.Parameters["ID"].Value = strID;
                            adapter.Update(ds);
                            dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
       }
```

but why when i clicking the "delete" button, it is delete all records in the datagridview, but it does not updating to the database? And also i want that only a selected row that has been selected that is gonna be delete.

Thanks

Comment: You put the `WHERE` clause at the end of your query.

Comment: What is the DataSource of the DataGridView? Does the row have primary key information (you mention ID 9, but is this unique?) Also where is this code? In an event handler of the DataGridView or somewhere else?

Comment: yeah, but i don't know what to put in the "WHERE" clause. I mean, how do i let the computer know when i select the value(s) in datagridview, and click "delete" button, and it will be deleted in datagridview and database. What should i do? Thanks

Comment: hai Lc, i mention ID 9, the ID in database is autonumber, like in the picture above. I think, it is unique. Because it is auto generate the number. The code above is on "Delete" function, when the delete button has been clicked, the code above will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this example code:

```
string query = "DELETE FROM [Record] WHERE ID = 9";
```

Or from some control for example:

```
string query = "DELETE FROM [Record] WHERE ID =" + idTextBox.Text;
```

Update for SelectedRow:

```
deleteButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DeleteRecord);

private DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    int rowIdToDelete = row.Cells[ID].Value;
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        string query = "DELETE FROM [Record] WHERE ID = " + rowIdToDelete;
                        conn.Open();

                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                            {
                                DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                                adapter.Update(ds);
                                dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hai Yair Nevet, your code is run and delete the row when i select the row which is have 100 in ID. Other than that is not doing anything or error. I want let the computer know when the user select a row, and click "delete" button, it will be deleted in datagridview, as well in database. Thanks. On your example in `from some control`, how do i do that? because it is on datagridview, not in control.

Comment: what is ID in row.Cells[ID]?

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra That's exactly what you need.. the id of whatever column name what contains the row's id.

Comment: okay, thanks dude. But, how do i retrieve that value of id? So, when the user select row 0, the ID will be changed to "0", when the user select row 1, the ID will be changed to "1". I don't know how to do it in dataGridView, i only know when it is use the control. Furthermore, i have curious how do i do that in dataGridView. Thank you very much!

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra You have a delete button in each row or only one delete button out of the datagridview?

Comment: Hai @YairNevet, i already tried your code with change the `ID` to `0`, but when i run the program, and click delete button, nothing changed. I have one delete button out of the datagridview. The screenshot will be on my question. Please refer to it. Thank you

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra Please attach the image to your question - I can't see it from the link you sent.

Comment: I am sorry, just now, my reputation is below than 10, so this forum not allowed me to post the photos. Please refer to the question again @YairNevet

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra Do you select any row in the grid before clicking the delete button? My code should iteratre over selected rows and if no selected rows so nothing would happen.

Comment: yeah, i selected row in the grid, after that i click the delete button, but nothing happens

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra Just debug it - see what is going on.

Comment: no, it is not working @YairNevet. I already edited the code in my question. Please refer to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `where` condition in your delete statement.

Something like this:-

```
  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "DELETE FROM [Record] WHERE ID =" + idTextBox.Text;
                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                    {
                        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Update(ds);
                        dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hai rahul tripathi, On your example it is mention `ID = idTextBox.Text`, how do i do that? because it is on datagridview, not in control.